# Meteor How to create a Invite system

Tags: javascript, html, meteor

I want to make a small invite system (User send an email to the friend with an ivitation code --> friend clicks on the public website everyone can go --> puts his invitation code in the text field and meteor searches for this code if it can find the code all is fine and he can continue but when meteor cant find the code he is one random internet user and he shouldnt can continue

So I need something which compares the inputted value with the data in the collection

this is my js file maybe some good things are already inside of it ;)

```
Template.Invite.onCreated(function() {
    this.subscribe('invites');
});

Template.Invite.events({
  'submit .Invite'(event)  {
    event.preventDefault();
    var Invite = event.target.Invite.value;

  }
});

Template.Invite.helpers({
    results: function(){
        return Invites.find({
          code: Session.get('Invite'),

          if (Invite = Invite)
          {
            FlowRouter.go('/');
          }


        });
    }
});
```

my publish part in the main.js

```
Meteor.publish("invites", function() {
      return Invites.find();
  })
```

and the not important html

```
<template name="Invite">
    <form class="Invite" >
            <input type="text" name="Invite" placeholder="Invite Code" />
            <input type="submit" value="Bestätigen" />
        </form>
</template>
```

the insert in the Invite Collection works already but not the find and the compare

Thank you for your time and help ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've created an invitation system a few times and this is how I did it.

When the user sends an invitation, you create a new document in the Invitation collection like this:

```
import { Random } from 'meteor/random';

const code = Random.hexString(16);

invitation = {
    'code': code,
    'sentTo': 'user@website.com',
    'accepted': false,
}
```

Then when a user tries to sign up you need to call a method that grabs their invitation code and compares it to the code in the database

```
Meteor.methods({
    'acceptInvitation'(code) {
        check(code, String);

        // find invitation in database
        let invitation = Invitations.findOne({ 'code': code});

        //check if invitation exists and if it hasn't already been accepted
        if(invitation && invitation.accepted == false) {
            //update invitation to now be accepted
            Invitations.update(
                { '_id': invitation._id},
                { $set: { accepted: true }
            );
            return true;
        } else {
            throw new Meteor.Error('invalid', 'Your invitation code is not valid');
        }
    }
});
```

To make your invitation system even better, when you are sending the invitation email you can pass the invitation code as a parameter in the URL. Then when the user clicks the invitation link you can grab the code from the URL and automatically put it in the registration form for them. This prevents them making mistakes when they copy/paste it!

Comment: This is a common and effective pattern. Using a route for the invitation link like `/invitation/:_id` makes it easy to email someone an invitation link. I use the `_id` of the `Invitation` object as the unique invitation link. I also track how many times the link has been clicked to help measure conversion rates in the funnel invitation > click > signup

Comment: Hi @Sean this code is genius thank you really much  (is the Meteor /random a package?)

Comment: now I have a small problem i get the message check is undefined ;(

Comment: Do I need @Sean so you get a message?

Comment: found it ;) check is also a packkage ;)

Comment: new error ;( => Meteor server restarted
I20170210-22:09:51.670(1)? Exception while invoking method 'acceptInvitation' Ty
peError: Cannot read property 'findOne' of undefined

Comment: @Michael you need to import pretty much everything you use. Invitations is undefined because you haven't imported the collection.

I suggest you read this article: https://themeteorchef.com/tutorials/understanding-the-imports-directory

Comment: ha now it works it was a typo ;) i did not imported my collection but it works without